# Spring custom repository for MingoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, repository, spring-data-mongodb

Tell me how to properly implement your repository for mongodb?
At the moment, with this configuration, for some reason I get an error .... ((

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "by.repository.mongo", repositoryBaseClass = BaseMongoRepository.class)
public class MongoConfig {}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseMongoRepository<T extends BaseDocument> extends MongoRepository<T, String> {

  void saveCascade(T document);

}

public interface LimitRepository extends BaseMongoRepository<LimitDocument>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<LimitDocument> {}

public class LimitRepositoryImpl extends BaseMongoRepositoryImpl<LimitDocument> implements BaseMongoRepository<LimitDocument> {

  public LimitRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<LimitDocument, String> metadata, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
    super(metadata, mongoOperations);
  }

  @Override
  public void saveCascade(LimitDocument document) {
    save(document);
  }
```

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in by.repository.mongo.LimitRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' in your configuration.

**UPDATE 1**

I have found simple solution...
But I would like to know if there are pitfalls in such a decision

```
public class LimitRepositoryImpl extends BaseMongoRepositoryImpl<LimitDocument> implements BaseMongoRepository<LimitDocument> {
...
  public LimitRepositoryImpl(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
    super(getEntityInformationFor(LimitDocument.class, String.class), mongoOperations);
  }
...
  public static MongoEntityInformation getEntityInformationFor(Class clazz, Class idClazz) {
    TypeInformation typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(clazz);
    MongoPersistentEntity mongoPersistentEntity = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity(typeInformation);
    return new MappingMongoEntityInformation(mongoPersistentEntity, idClazz);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code for `getEntityInformationFor`! Made it easy to use the Spring `MongoRepository` without needing to use the rest of the Repository framework

Comment: Ok, it turns out the `getEntityInformationFor` above does not set the id property accurately, so Spring is unable to use methods like `findById`. To resolve it, I made a custom Bean ```    @Bean
    public MongoRepositoryFactory mongoRepositoryFactory(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        return new MongoRepositoryFactory(mongoOperations);
    }``` and then invoked that bean to make the `MongoEntityInformation`: `factory.getEntityInformation(MyEntity.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method
Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<PersonEntity, Integer>{}
```

And in your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.data"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.data"})
public class PersonApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PersonApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Yes, that's how it works... But I want to create my own repository with NoRepositoryBean

Comment: Ideally, I need to create my own saveCascade method, which in its work will call the default save method

Comment: You can also use MongoTemplate:
 
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;